# Is it possible to physically reorganize a mongoDB collection to avoid using a sort()?

Tags: mongodb, optimization

I have a collection that stores information about articles. The collection is for archival purposes so it is read only. Only two fields are being used at the moment: "title" and "page_length". Because I am always interested in getting longer articles first, I have the following index in place: { title: 1, page_length: -1}.

I have found that sorts are still slow because the collection is very large and won't fit into memory.

Assuming that almost *every* query I use on this collection will require a sort({page_length:-1}), is there any way to simply have the records stored on disk in order of page_length descending? In other words, is there a simple way to make the first record in the collection the largest page_length value, the second record the second largest, and so on?

That way I could just grab the first n records using limit(n) without having to run a sort. Any ideas?

---

Updating with more information:

I'm using this for a search autocomplete feature so speed is critical. The query I've been using looks like this:

`db.articles.find({"title": /^SomeKeyword/}).sort({page_length:-1})`

I'm happy to create multiple indexes since inserts are not a concern, I just want to maximize read speed.

**EDIT:** For reference, I actually was able to reorganize the records in the collection by using a find().forEach() into a new collection. I then searched the collection and grabbed the first N results without the need for any sort, which worked very well. Note that this ONLY works because my dataset does not ever change.

Answer (score 1):

Your index `{ title: 1, page_length: -1 }` is not used for the a query that looks like this:

```
db.collection.find( {} ).sort( { page_length: -1 } );
```

MongoDB can only use compound indexes from left to right, so in order for the index to be used, you need to have the "title" as a find or sort argument:

db.collection.find( { title: 'foo' } ).sort( { page_length: -1 } );
   db.collection.find().sort( { title: 1, page_length: -1 } );

Explain will tell you:

```
db.so.find( {} ).sort( { page_length: -1 } ).explain();

{
    "cursor" : "BasicCursor",
    …
```

If you change your index to:

```
db.so.ensureIndex({ page_length: -1, title: 1 } );
```

Then the index will be used for sorting, but you can't use the index for just doing a lookup by `title` and you will need an additional index for that. If you're really only interested in those two fields and making sure you use a covered index helps. You will have to have the compound index with `{ page_length: -1, title: 1 }` and you can make sure it is used by using a projection:

db.collection.find( {}, { page_length: 1, title: 1, _id: 0 } ).sort( { page_length: -1 } );

But you can not decide or influence how MongoDB stores things on disk.

Comment: Thank you! I added some more details to the question. Do you think I should create one index for the title and one compound index for the sort?

Comment: Also, +1 for catching the fact that my index isn't really working.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a solution that uses two queries.

First, you can do a [covered query](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-indexes-to-support-queries/#indexes-covered-queries) to get the list of documents you care about.  Second you can use the list of documents retrieved and the [`$in`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/in/) operator to get the final result.

The covered query will operate within memory (or at least sequentially on disk), so it should be fast, and the `$in` can utilize the `_id` index and should be tolerably efficient with a reasonable number of documents.

Comment: Can you give me example syntax of how I could do that?